# Column missing from table

Tags: sql, asp.net

Recently i created a table and added a new data as images to the database in visual studio asp.net c#. 
When i right click and show table data, the column for the images is missing and not there even though i have updated the table itself

Is there anything that i have missed out?

Thanks 
[image][image]

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: Your explanation is extremely poor. Where are you doing that clicking? Are the columns there in SSMS? Maybe your schema in Visual Studio is out-of-sync?

Comment: @Andrew i am doing it under the server explorer

Comment: And where you do see all the columns?

Comment: @Andrew i have updated my question with the picture attached

Comment: What's the result when you excute`select * from ExerciseInstrcutions` on SSMS,Is there display `image` column?

Comment: Was the table saved after adding the column? I see that the Design tab has a *, meaning it's not saved. If you expand the table node no the left, do you get the `Images` column? Finally, although unrelated, why are you using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`? Will you be using Unicode characters? At least in urls I don't think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your SQL database
in option->designers->Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

unchecked this
I hope your problem are solved